# SQL isnull fails with try_cast

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isnull

I am trying to handle some data in the following way.

- If the entry is numeric, cast it as an integer.
- If the entry is not numeric, keep it as it is.

I am using 'try_cast' to cast my numeric entries to my integers. This gives NULL if the entry is not numeric.

```
declare @code varchar(3) = 'fff'
select try_cast(@code as int) as code
```

I then thought, well if I catch the null with an isnull I will be able to output the original value as I wanted.

```
declare @code varchar(3) = 'fff'
select isnull( try_cast(@code as int), @code) as code
```

However I get a conversion failed error.

I did not expect this behavior. Why is this happening and how can I acheive the desired behaviour?

Comment: What is your situation that you have a data point/column which might or might not be numeric?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is correct. I have a field which may contain numeric data, for which I need to compare as an integer. Otherwise, I need to compare as the string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRY_CAST(... as int)` return INT data type, 
`ISNULL(INT, VARCHAR(3))` leads both to INT

> [ISNULL: Returns the same type as check_expression.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
declare @code varchar(3) = '123'
select ISNULL(CAST(try_cast(@code as int) as VARCHAR(3)),@code ) as code
```

may use

> [COALESCE: Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type
>   precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

but INT upper VARCHAR in 
[Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: This gives the desired behavior. The replacement value has to be the same type as the inner expression.

Comment: No, it's not obligatory. Must implement an implicit conversion

Answer (score 1):

You are having a type-conversion error, because of the incompatibility.  The column is *either* an integer or a string, but not both.

When you have two types in an expression, the numeric one dominates.  In other words, SQL Server attempts to convert the string value to a number.  Of course, this fails when done implicitly when `try_convert()` fails.

I would suggest two columns:

```
select try_cast(@code as int) as int_code, @code as orig_code
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a block of code within a larger body of code, yes? As in, you're not trying to have a function dynamically return different data types based on the input?

If so, can you use `sql_variant_property` via an if-else block to direct flow of control? e.g.

`declare @code varchar(3) = 'fff'
 if SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@code,'BaseType') = 'INT'
 begin
    print 'do numeric comparison'
 end
 else
 begin
    print 'do string comparison'
 end`

Comment: Actually, I may not completely understood your scenario; it looks like you're actually using the `varchar(3)` parameter, which may contain a numeric-convertible string. In that case, I'd make a slight change to the if-else block: replace the `if` comparison with `if try_cast(@code as int) is not null`.